# resize all images if width > something jquery

Tags: jquery, resize

i want to resize all images in a page if width is > for example 400px

i try with this code

```
 var img_width =  $("#my_img").width();
//alert(img_width)
if(img_width > 380){
 $("#my_img").width('380');
}
```

but no thing work and on the page i have more than 10 pic ti has id my_img

the img tag

img src='tttttt.jpg'  id="my_img"

how i can resize it ?

coz i have a template and i dont want width of img is more than 400px

Comment: It is invalid html to have more than one item with the same `id`.  Use `class`es instead.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use CSS for this?

`max-width:400px;`

And like Daedalus said using the same id multiple times in one document is invalid html.

Comment: Don't forget to accept this answer as an accepted answer if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".my_img").each(function(e){
            if(e.width()>380){
                jQuery(this).attr('width','380');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is invalid html to have more than one item with the same `id`.  As I said in my comment above, uses a `class` instead.

Assuming your html is like the following:

```
<img class="my_img" src="someurl" style="width: 390px;" />
<img class="my_img" src="someurl" style="width: 390px;" />
<img class="my_img" src="someurl" style="width: 390px;" />
<img class="my_img" src="someurl" style="width: 340px;" />
```

The following jquery will resize the first three images, given they match the corresponding rule:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.my_img').each(function(index,value) {
        if ($(value).width() > 380) {
            $(this).css('width', 380);
        }
    });
});​
```